# Is it possible to add Menu Items to a context menu during implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I hope I asked the right question, but here's my situation. I have a `TreeViewItem` that I'm implementing. Inside it I set/add various properties, one of them being a `ContextMenu`. All I want to do is add `MenuItems` to the `ContextMenu` without passing to functions and such.

Here's how I implement my `TreeViewItem` with `ContextMenu`:

```
public static TreeViewItem Item = new TreeViewItem() //Child Node
{
        ContextMenu = new ContextMenu //CONTEXT MENU
        {
            Background = Brushes.White,
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),

            //**I would like to add my MENUITEMS here if possible
        }
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonhja answer is correct. Providing a example for your case.

```
        TreeViewItem GreetingItem = new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header = "Greetings",
            ContextMenu = new ContextMenu //CONTEXT MENU
            {
                Background = Brushes.White,
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
            }
        };

        MenuItem sayGoodMorningMenu = new MenuItem() { Header = "Say Good Morning" };
        sayGoodMorningMenu.Click += (o, a) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Good Morning");
        };
        MenuItem sayHelloMenu = new MenuItem() { Header = "Say Hello" };
        sayHelloMenu.Click += (o, a) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            };
        GreetingItem.ContextMenu.Items.Add(sayHelloMenu);
        GreetingItem.ContextMenu.Items.Add(sayGoodMorningMenu);
        this.treeView.Items.Add(GreetingItem);
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was the one I used to get my program working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For that purpose in `WPF` I did this:

```
TreeViewItem GreetingItem = new TreeViewItem()
    {
        Header = "Greetings",
        ContextMenu = new ContextMenu //CONTEXT MENU
        {
            Background = Brushes.White,
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
        }
    };

// Create ContextMenu
contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.Closing += contextMenu_Closing;

// Exit item
MenuItem menuItemExit = new MenuItem
{
      Header = Cultures.Resources.Exit,
      Icon= Cultures.Resources.close
};
menuItemExit.Click += (o, a) =>
{
     Close();
}

// Restore item
MenuItem menuItemRestore = new MenuItem
{
    Header = Cultures.Resources.Restore,
    Icon= Cultures.Resources.restore1
};
menuItemRestore.Click += (o, a) =>
{
     WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
};

contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItemRestore);
contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItemExit);               

GreetingItem.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

You can set it to any element that supports so.

**EDIT:** I'm writing it by memory, sorry if it's not exact. But more or less that's the idea.

Comment: This will help me add events to these items, thank you very much!