# XamlParseException was Unhandled when adding MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, xamlparseexception

During implementing the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080363/is-it-possible-to-add-menu-items-to-a-context-menu-during-implementation?answertab=oldest#tab-top) I came across the `XamlParseException` run-time error.

I will explain when the error occurs, because it doesn't make any sense to me. First of all, I use the solution from the previous question to build two `Context Menus` that come down when the user right-clicks the `TreeViewitems`.

**EDIT:** For better understanding, I'm going to post the code exactly how I have it. I am still receiving the error after switching my code to this.

```
public static TreeViewItem item1 = new TreeViewItem();
public static TreeViewItem item2 = new TreeViewItem();

ContextMenu item1_CM = new ContextMenu() { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Black, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1) };
        MenuItem add1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Add..." }; //Add & Delete MenuItems
        MenuItem delete1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete..." };

ContextMenu item2_CM = new ContextMenu() { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Black, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1) };
        MenuItem add2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Add..." }; //Add & Delete MenuItems
        MenuItem delete2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete..." };

public constructor()
{
     Tree = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();
     Tree.Add(item1);
     Tree.Add(item2);

     //Add MenuItems to TreeView ContextMenus
     item1_CM.Items.Add(add1);
     item1_CM.Items.Add(delete1);
     item1.Items.Add(item1_CM);

     item2_CM.Items.Add(add2);
     item2_CM.Items.Add(delete2);
     item2.Items.Add(item2_CM);
}
```

I add two `MenuItems` EXACTLY like this for two `TreeViewItems`. If I compile and run with the first set implemented, the program runs fine, but after adding new `MenuItems` to the other `TreeViewItem`, I get that `XamlParseException was unhandled` error. What could be causing this?

Thanks for your help.

**XAML As requested**

```
<Window x:Class="CircularButtonPrototype.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:cmp="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="Window1" MinHeight="685" MaxHeight="685" Height="685" MinWidth="1044" MaxWidth="1044" Width="1044" AllowsTransparency="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Visibility="Visible">
</Window>
```

My `TreeView` in `XAML`:

```
<TreeView Name="Tree_One" ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" SelectedItemChanged="Tree_One_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

Comment: Can you poste your XAML code? It seems like if you have something irregular there.

Comment: Sure, just the top section, down to the `Title`? Also, just a note, I have not touched my XAML since the last question.

Comment: But I can only see the code behind. Where did you post your XAML?

Comment: What exactly does the error say and is there an inner `Exception`, as there usually is with `XamlParseException` objects?

Comment: I don't see anything about an inner `Exception`, but the error is that standard: `Cannot create instance of 'Window1' defined in assembly 'CircularButtonPrototype, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.`

Comment: Where is the `InitializeComponent` at your constructor? It should appear AFTER you create the new ObservableCollection();

Comment: Finally I could reproduce your mistake. One min to check what's wrong.

Comment: Cool, and no `InitializeComponent` because this is all in a different class. Compare it to a `ViweModel` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is at this line:

```
 item1.Items.Add(item1_CM);
 ...
 item2.Items.Add(item2_CM);
```

Change it by this:

```
item1.ContextMenu = item1_CM;
...
item2.ContextMenu = item2_CM;
```

Is it possible to reuse code like this?

```
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> Tree { get; set; }

    public static TreeViewItem Item = new TreeViewItem {Header = "MainTreeViewItem"};
    public static TreeViewItem Item2 = new TreeViewItem {Header = "MainTreeViewItem"};

    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Black, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1) };
    MenuItem addItem = new MenuItem() { Header = "Add..." }; //Add & Delete MenuItems
    MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete..." };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Tree = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();
        //Add MenuItems to TreeView ContextMenus
        contextMenu.Items.Add(addItem);
        contextMenu.Items.Add(deleteItem);

        Item.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
        Item2.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

        Tree.Add(Item);
        Tree.Add(Item2);
    }
```

NOTE: you will be using the same `ContextMenu` for both. Use it and try to check which item is the one sending the event to delete the appropiate one ;)

Comment: I should probably ask a new question about this, but how would I implement adding click events for these `MenuItems` if both `TreeViewItems` share the same `ContextMenu`?

Comment: I haven't tried that explicitly, but I think you could check which element is the sender and then act consecuently. But I think it would be easier to create a different ContextMenu for each one.